# App class acess?

Tags: wpf

I have a problem with App classб please help me!
I have App class, that in Main() functions starts Splash screen dialog and gets some results and after this calls

```
  StartupUri = new System.Uri("MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative); 

        Run();
```

The question is - how to access the App fields from MainFrame with or without using constructor if possible?

Comment: Do you mean fields that are in App.xaml.cs

Comment: if (App.Current.Properties["DragImage"] != null) - in Main Frame while in App there is public string property(getter/setter) DragImage but it allways returns null((  : "  App.Current.Properties Member 'System.Windows.Application.Current.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead 
"

Comment: what's App? Get rid of all variables and use *static* System.Windows.Application.Current :)

Comment: Dmitry) I use it! the App and System.Windows.Application.Current is the same! by the way I have paste your code in my IF and get the same null value (field is already initialized in app but...)

Comment: where do you get your splash screen kicked off from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the fields via:

```
((App)Application.Current).SomePropertyOfApp = ...
```